# is it good practice to reload a div every second

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on a networking site where I need to reload the notification div *every second*. I wanted to know is it good or bad to load it every second as there are some other divs *also* loading after every 3-4 seconds. Will it cause any problem like hanging, slowing down, etc?

Reloading is done by ajax:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()  {
        $('#notif').load('notiffinder.php #NOOFFNOTIFFC').fadeIn();
        $('#jtoloadnot').load('header.php #jtoloadnot').fadeIn();
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Basically you know that creating something cheap that consumes resources and has no value is not even considered useful for learning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't tell you if it will cause problems because it entirely depends on what you are putting into that div, your internet connection, and what kind of load you have on the server.

But you need to ask yourself, do you really *need* to be polling multiple php scripts every second?  Is the data actually changing every second?  I suspect you probably should be investigating other techniques, such as websockets and long-polling.

Comment: thankyou for answering and guiding me ... i will be highly thankfull if you just give a brief about how to use webshockets please ..

Comment: I've not used websockets... but I'm sure there are many resources available online to get you started.